# Regex-- How to extract the text after the second hyphen for each parenthesis?

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I am new to the Regex and the grammar made me confused. Here is the original string field : `(f-dqcn-bus1),(f-cdqc-bus2)`

I would like to have the new result like `bus1,bus2`.

There could be one or several parenthesis but the bus name is always after the second hyphen in each parenthesis. I plan to use the `str.findall(regex_pattern)` to extract, and could anyone help to develop the regex_pattern here? Thanks very much!

Comment: Can anything else follow after `bus1` within the parentheses?

Comment: No, not in my case. There are only two hyphens in one parenthesis.

Comment: Wow, a month later a reaction ;-) Have no idea anymore what this was about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match chars after a dash and before a bracket, and that are neither dash nor bracket:

```
businesses = re.findall(r"(?<=-)[^-)]+(?=\))", str)
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/ZOPXj2).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. But I missed a colon in the input. The input should be "(f-dqcn-bus:1),(f-cdqc-bus:2)". And the expected output is "bus:1,bus:2". Could you help to update the regex pattern? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this works for you but I've tried it before and I kinda love .str methods in Pandas!

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('f-dqcn-bus1'), ('f-cdqc-bus2')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column_name'])
tuple(df['column_name'].str.split('-', n = 2, expand = True)[2])

# ('bus1', 'bus2')
```